# Put the pink div behind the silver div and make sure that we can hover the pink div after doing that

Tags: html, css

I want to put the pink sliding box behind the silver menu bar. Also if you are changing the z-index to -1 then make sure to be able to hover over the pink div as well, because it disappears as soon as you move your mouse away from the main link. Thanks in advance.

I have tried changing the z-index at multiple areas, have it applied on un ordered list as well

I want the menu to slide down like this website has https://www.storyblocks.com/browse/stock-vectors

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

.main-div {
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  background: silver;
}

.items {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px;
}

.sub-item {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  background: pink;
  height: 300px;
  display: none;
}

.items:hover .sub-item {
  display: block;
  animation-name: example;
  animation-duration: 4s;
}

@keyframes example {
  from {
    margin-top: -300px;
  }
  to {
    margin-top: 0px;
  }
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <div class="main-div">
    <div class="items">T-Shirts
      <div class="sub-item">this is sub item</div>
    </div>
    <div class="items">T-Shirts</div>
    <div class="items">T-Shirts</div>
    <div class="items">T-Shirts</div>
    <div class="items">T-Shirts</div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: so in addition to z-index:-1 simply add the hover effect on the submenu item

Comment: Thank you so much for replying. Could you please suggest the where should I make these changes? I am unable to understand why is it happening.

Comment: `.items:hover .sub-item {}` --> `.items:hover .sub-item,.sub-item:hover {}`

Comment: Didn't work. Still can't hover over the pink sliding div.

Answer (score 0):

How about you animate the height instead of the margin?

CHANGES

```
.sub-item {
  height: 0px;
  top: 28px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

@keyframes example {
  from {
    height: 0px;
  }
  to {
    height: 300px;
  }
}
```

HTML

```
<nav>
  <div class="main-div">
    <div class="items">T-Shirts
      <div class="sub-item">this is sub item</div>
    </div>
    <div class="items">T-Shirts</div>
    <div class="items">T-Shirts</div>
    <div class="items">T-Shirts</div>
    <div class="items">T-Shirts</div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

CSS

```
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

.main-div {
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  background: silver;
}

.items {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px;
}

.sub-item {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  background: pink;
  height: 0px;
  top: 28px;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: none;
}

.items:hover .sub-item {
  display: block;
  animation-name: example;
  animation-duration: 4s;
}

@keyframes example {
  from {
    height: 0px;
  }
  to {
    height: 300px;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I tried changing the height, and it seemed perfect until I added the content within the pink div. So when I hover over the main link the content is visible immediately but div slides slowly.

Comment: @SiddharthaSharma do you want to send me the content you are putting into it? You can also animate `max-height` for dynamic content but if it doesn't suit you can also use a sibling selector to get around the issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
   *{
       margin: 0px;
       padding: 0px;
   }
   .main-div{
       text-align: center;
       position: relative;
       background: silver;
   }
   .items{
       display: inline-block;
       padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px;
   }
   .sub-item{
       position: absolute;
       width: 100%;
       left: 0;
       background: pink;
       height: 300px;
       display: none;
       margin-top: 1px;
       z-index: -1;
   }
   .items:hover .sub-item, .sub-item:hover{
       display: block;
       animation-name: example;
       animation-duration: 1s;
   }
   @keyframes example {
   from {margin-top:-300px;}
   to {margin-top:0px;}
   }
</style>

<nav>
   <div class="main-div">
       <div class="items">T-Shirts
           <div class="sub-item">this is sub item

               <ul>

                   <li>item</li>
                   <li>item</li>
                   <li>item</li>
               </ul>
           </div>
       </div>
       <div class="items">T-Shirts</div>
       <div class="items">T-Shirts</div>
       <div class="items">T-Shirts</div>
       <div class="items">T-Shirts</div>
   </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: I want pink div to slide in and stay. I would also love to know the reason why it is happening like this only after adding `z-index:-1;`